# Recording the Returned values return by sample function

Tags: r, sample

I need to create a throw function that returns a random number between 1 to 6 every time the user uses the throw() function. But i need to record the values that the user got in a variable that the user is not aware of. The idea is that i can cross verify the reported values and actual values at some later point of time.

I went about it like this

```
throw<-function(){
   dice<-c(1:6)
    A<-c(0,0)
       x<-sample(dice,1)
        fetches<-c(A,x)
          x
}
```

I thought that calling the fetches variable would get me the required vector.But i am getting the output "object not found" while calling for fetches

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an "invisible" environment and pre-allocate for a bunch of values:

```
#objects with a name starting with . are invisible
.e <- new.env(, parent = .GlobalEnv)
#pre-allocate
.e$fetches <- integer(100)

throw<-function(){ 
  dice <- c(1:6)
  x <- sample(dice,1)
  #check if vector has room for new values, grow if necessary
  if (sum(.e$fetches == 0L) == 0L) .e$fetches <- c(.e$fetches, integer(100))
  .e$fetches[which.min(.e$fetches)] <- x
  return("complete")
}

set.seed(42)
throw()
#[1] "complete"
throw()
#[1] "complete"
.e$fetches[.e$fetches != 0L]
#[1] 6 6
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I am planning to integrate this with a shiny app. Will having an invisible environment interfere with that?

Comment: I don't have experience with shiny. I wouldn't expect problems, but I don't really know.